# PHP bug or just a logical flaw

Tags: php, comparison, operators

I need to know why, the real logical reason, that the following comparison is executing the "echo" line! It seems to be some kind of sorcery. If you take out the "+" sign, it won't work. If you leave it as it is, it will!

```
<?php
  $fromUnits = "2";
  $toUnits = "100000000+";
  
  if ($fromUnits >= $toUnits) {
    echo "Bypassed."; // WHY?
  }
?>
```

Comment: and to add info from docs: [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) _"Prior to PHP 8.0.0, if a string is compared to a number or a numeric string then the string was converted to a number before performing the comparison. This can lead to surprising results"_

Comment: Because `"2" < "a lot"` etc., however `"2" > "!"` etc. when you compare strings. `100000000+` is not a well-formed number. Also `"2" != "two"` and `"TWO" < "two"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two string values are able to be coerced into numeric values, they are compared as numbers.  And the *number* `100000000` is indeed greater than tha *number* `2`.

However, if both strings *can't* be coerced into numbers, they are compared as strings.  And the *string* `"2"` is "greater than" the *string* `"100000000+"`, in terms of being sorted alphabetically.

Comment: And how this isn't considered a flaw?

Comment: @KonKarOtMa: I suppose that's a matter of opinion to be taken up with the maintainers of the PHP language.  I'm personally a fan of stricter type checking these days, but PHP is far from the only language that has a variety of type coersion rules.